# How to model noisy time series data? Does non-linear modelling help?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science-model

Is it possible to model time series data that fluctuates. The main solution is to take first differences and make it easier to fit conventional models. What if non-linear models are built? Can they solve a noisy time series (e.g stock returns) and make good predictions? Can adding a square term or a trigonometric term or something else non-linear work? Has some researched the topic?